# Error: "Map Container not found" when using "ngfor"

Tags: angular, leaflet, ngx-leaflet

Environment:
Angular 9,
Leaflet 1.6.0
ngx-leaflet 7.0.0

Background:
I can build multiple maps by creating individual "div" and "options" without any issue with the commented portion of html

when I switch to using "ngfor" to create multiple maps in same page, I get the above error, stack trace is below.

Code Snippet:
realtimedashb.component.html

```
<!-- <div id="testmap">
  </div> 
  <div id="testmap2">
  </div> -->
  <div *ngFor="let widget of widgets; let w = index" class="col-md-{{widget.width}}">
    <div #id="map{{widget.name}}" >
  </div>
  </div>
```

realtimedashb.component.ts

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';

@component

leafletoptions(widget){

// this code works fine for hardcoded div's
/* const map = L.map('testmap').setView([50.6311634, 3.0599573], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: 'Test Map',
maxZoom: 12
}).addTo(map);
var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(40.6311634, 3.0599573), {
});
map.addLayer(marker);
map.invalidateSize(true);
const map2 = L.map('testmap2').setView([50.6311634, 3.0599573], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: 'Test Map',
maxZoom: 12
}).addTo(map2);
var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(40.6311634, 3.0599573), {
});
map2.addLayer(marker);
map2.invalidateSize(true);
*/

// Fails when I switch to ngfor and in this case parameter within L.Map is dynamic coming from backend, which is also used in the div.
var testmap = L.map(String(widget.name)).setView([50.6311634, 3.0599573], 4);
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: 'Test Map',
maxZoom: 12
}).addTo(testmap);
var marker = new L.Marker(new L.LatLng(50.6311634, 3.0599573), {
});
// testmap.invalidateSize(true);
testmap.addLayer(marker);
}
```

ERROR reported in Console.

```
Error: Map container not found.
at NewClass._initContainer (leaflet-src.js:4097)
at NewClass.initialize (leaflet-src.js:3131)
at new NewClass (leaflet-src.js:301)
at Object.createMap [as map] (leaflet-src.js:4718)
at RealtimeDashbComponent.leafletoptions (realtimedashb.component.ts:1749)
at RealtimeDashbComponent.setWidgetData (realtimedashb.component.ts:2076)
at realtimedashb.component.ts:1718
at Array.forEach ()
at SafeSubscriber._next (realtimedashb.component.ts:1715)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
```

I have also tried the following combinations

hardocded div and options -- works

hardcoded div and server derived options loop -- works

switching from hardcoded div to ngfor is where the problem occurs. I can see that the div is assigned to proper id passed in widget.name and is also reflected in the image at the this link.
[leaflet src file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uurd.jpg)

Comment: Have you looked in the debugg mode at the moment when the error is thrown, if the div with the id is existing? Your id in the image is `leaf29` is there a div with this id?

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to be using ngx-leaflet (unless what you included is just missing a bunch of context).  And the lack of formatting makes it hard to tell what's going on. You should probably include more complete code examples and make sure they are formatted.